# What is the best solution to comparing specific columns against two pandas dataframes here?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes with the same columns, one is old and one is new. They have a subset set of matching account numbers and I have done the following changes to create versions of these two dataframes which have the same account numbers/row length:

```
#Merge and find out where the commonality is in the accounts
m = old_df.merge(new_df, on='account_number', how='outer', suffixes=['', '_'], indicator=True)
m_both = m[m['_merge'] == 'both']

#Create a version of the old file which has the matching account numbers
old_df['both'] = old_df ['account_number'].isin(m_both['account_number'].unique())
old_both = old_df[old_df['both'] == True]

#Create a version of the new file which has the matching account numbers
new_df['both'] = new_df['account_number'].isin(m_both['account_number'].unique())
new_both = new_df[new_df['both'] == True]
```

Here is where my curiosity lies. Within both dataframes, there is a column called 'residence'. The new df has different values in some accounts under this column, compared to the old df. What would be the best way to identify/flag these different rows in the new df?

Example:

old df:

[image]

new df:

[image]

I have included code to create these dataframes below:

```
data = {'Account number': ['1234568','1111111','1111111','1414141','9898536','2360660','1144569','4488755','1122369'],
        'Residence': ['VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH','SINGAPORE','INDIA','VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH','VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH','BAHAMAS','VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH','SWITZERLAND','SWITZERLAND']}

old_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = {'Account number': ['1234568','1111111','1111111','1414141','9898536','2360660','1144569','4488755','1122369'],
        'Residence': ['VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH','SINGAPORE','SINGAPORE','VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH','VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH','VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH','VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH','VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH','SWITZERLAND']}

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: 1- your quotes are incorrect. 2- what would be the expected output?

Comment: Thanks I have edited the quotes. Ideally I’d like some way to flag on the new df which rows are different. So a new column ‘match’ to say yes or no.

Comment: The quotes are still off. Can you provide the explicit output? The logic is ambiguous as you have duplicated account numbers. Do you want to match on index (=line number)?

Comment: I will edit the quotes when I return to my computer thanks. I would like to match on index yes. Wherever there is a difference in one of the lines, I would like it flagged.

Comment: it's actually ok now. Got confused by the comma in virgin islands ;)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, simply use equality and aggregate per row with `any`:

```
new_df['equal'] = old_df.eq(new_df).all(1)
```

Output:

```
  Account number                Residence  equal
0        1234568  VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH   True
1        1111111                SINGAPORE   True
2        1111111                SINGAPORE  False
3        1414141  VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH   True
4        9898536  VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH   True
5        2360660  VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH  False
6        1144569  VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH   True
7        4488755  VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH  False
8        1122369              SWITZERLAND   True
```

Comment: Thanks. I have several other columns I want to compare in the dataframe. The dataframe actually actually contains about 18 columns. Can I adapt the code to reference a specific column? Eg: ```new_df['residence_equal'] = old_df[‘residence’].eq(new_df[‘residence’]).all(1)```

Comment: @work_python you need `all` only if you compare more than 1 column. But yes, you can slice to limit the comparison to a subset